# How to make new tab when click search icon

Tags: html, css

I have been created search box using codepen,

```
<div id="wrap">
    <form action="" autocomplete="on">
        <input id="search" name="search" class="search-box" type="text" 
            placeholder="What're we looking for ?"><input id="search_submit"
            value="Rechercher" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/64vtfm0n/)

It works fine, but I need to show text input line in new tab.

Can anyone help?

Comment: please clarify what you mean by 'new tab'? Also, just to clarify (not that it makes much difference) - but that's a jsfiddle?

Comment: Use `value` in input - `<input value="">` - http://jsfiddle.net/64vtfm0n/1/

Comment: @jbutler483: when i click that icon .. it will go to next page..

Comment: What you mean by "i need to show text input line in new tab." What is this text input line?

Comment: if you want it to go to another page, then use an `<a>` attribute with a href?

Comment: Are you using javascipt, php, asp... we need a little more information about the forms action and your requirements

Comment: @LuisP.A.: when i click that icon,, it will go to new page.. thanks

Comment: no javascript and php at all.. it only html and css.. thanks

Comment: @jbutler483: may i know , how to make a href.. without change functionality in my demo?.. thanks

Comment: use a tag instead of the submit-input,for example,```<a href="/newpage"></a>```

Comment: @sona what you want to do can't be done with only html and css

Comment: @jbutler483: actually i need like  this http://www.gatesnotes.com/ , in this website search icon behavior i want.. i need same as for my web page.. thanks

Comment: @sona: please refer to my example for this. you will need to use a small bit of js to achieve this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of the website you have linked, you are looking to create somewhat of a modal popup. However, this can be achieved using something like the snippet below, with minimal JS.

Please note: I am not a js pro, so I have taken to jQuery (although this could be done in vanilla js I'm sure).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').css("display", "block");
    $('.button').css("display", "none");
  });

  $('#submitSearch').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').css("display", "none");
    $('.button').css("display", "block");
  });

});
```

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.button,
.overlay input[type="submit"] {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
  display: none;
}
.overlay input[type="text"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: -webkit-calc(100vw - 100px);
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}

/*for demo only*/
.mainContent{
  margin-top:100px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="overlay">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter search and press icon again" id="searchString" />
  <input id="submitSearch" type="submit" value="" />
</div>

<div class="mainContent">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae lobortis augue, vitae commodo ante. Cras mi odio, dictum non varius a, elementum quis lorem. Donec erat tellus, gravida a dui nec, ornare pulvinar felis. Pellentesque felis elit, venenatis eget rutrum nec, viverra id erat. Sed sit amet porta odio. Curabitur id elit at lectus convallis feugiat. Donec ac ullamcorper urna. Integer sagittis orci ante, non posuere est gravida vitae.

Fusce molestie tempus felis, id faucibus felis bibendum ut. Cras ut rutrum ipsum. Cras ut mi eros. Sed posuere tortor et dignissim varius. Donec viverra placerat nisi, quis laoreet tortor tempor a. Ut semper pretium nisi in porttitor. Aliquam mauris ipsum, lacinia a urna ut, rutrum auctor turpis. Suspendisse gravida leo nec eleifend luctus. Suspendisse vestibulum sem ut venenatis pretium. Quisque sagittis neque ut iaculis maximus. Aliquam ut aliquet turpis. Fusce eget odio sit amet mi porttitor facilisis eu eget augue.
  </div>
```

This works by first of all, using positioning on a button class to position the icon.

From there, hiding the `.overlay` class using css. You can then use JS to toggle the overlay div's display property.

Within the `.overlay` parent, a submit and input have been placed (using positioning) and the submit button is placed on top of the 'old' icon. When you press this 'new icon', it hides this 'popup' once again.

Comment: but when i type the keyword, it didn't search right? +1 for your ans...

Comment: @sona: that's a server side method. From pressing the 'submit', you should then add a mthod in your controller handling that.

Comment: but when i run your code in my localhost, it didn't work... thanks

Comment: when you say 'doesn't work' - what doesn't?

Comment: yes.. it is working.. thanks. can you please some advice about search the word within my website? continue from this work... i referred lot in google.. i heard something  lucense anr other some application.. but i don't how to use in my part of work.. can you please help me? thanks..

Comment: hello @ jbutler483: ... are you there?.

Comment: when i move to your answer to my existing page, it shows background color for half of the page only.. may i know to display full background color when click the search icon? thanks

Comment: set `overlay's` position to `fixed` instead of absolute. Otherwise, set `overlays height to 100% instead of 100vh.

Comment: okay thanks @jbutler483: but i added slider and and some form next search icon.. so it didn't disable.. but rest of others disable.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use "Window open() Method" on click of search icon, for window open() method you will need to create one new html file where you will need to add your search field.

Comment: can you provide example demo... with same functionality..

Comment: Check this link  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp instead of http://www.w3schools.com this page you will need to create your search field.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to click an icon and then go to another page, you just need to change your submit-input to an a element,check this

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/64vtfm0n/3/

what I did in this fiddle is change the input to an a-element,add href for it ,change z-index to 4 which is bigger than another input

```
<a id="search_submit" href="http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/64vtfm0n/2/" >
```

I guess what you need is  click icon then input something then submit it, you may need to explain what you really want exactly

Comment: not like that @super-xp: if we click that icon.. it will go to next page and show that line(my demo) What're we looking for ?

Comment: you can not do this without javascript,you need to explain your real intention  exactly ,that will help both of us

Comment: yeah ok... thats not matter, using javascript.. i need to like this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open .. as same as.. when i click that icon.. it shows What're we looking for ? in next page.. thanks